# Reshape "filling" by row

Tags: julia, reshape

Is there any easy way to reshape a vector into an array in which the "filling" is by row?

More specifically, suppose I have a vector

```
v = collect(1:8)
```

`reshape` "fills" the resulting array by column:

```
reshape(v, (2,2,2))

2x2x2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3
 2  4

[:, :, 2] =
 5  7
 6  8
```

But I want to get:

```
a = Array{Int}(2,2,2)
a[:, :, 1] = [1 2; 3 4]
a[:, :, 2] = [5 6; 7 8]

a
2x2x2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  2
 3  4

[:, :, 2] =
 5  6
 7  8
```

This would be a nice option to add to `reshape`.

Comment: You can do:  permutedims(v, (2,1,3)) on the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mapslices(transpose,reshape(v, (2,2,2)),[1,2])
```

The keyword you were missing is "transpose". The rest I just took from [the docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#Base.mapslices)